# Open multiple tables in MSSQL at once with editing mode (EDIT TOP 200 ROWS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sometimes to solve a certain issue I need to open (by open I mean right click => *EDIT TOP 200 ROWS*) about 5 different tables and do the necessary changes in them.

Is it possible to automate the opening of these 5 tables somehow?

I know I can do `SELECT * FROM TABLE1, SELECT * FROM TABLE2` and etc, but I need the regular interface of an open table.

In Notepad++ it would be like saving a session.

Thanks

Comment: No, but if what you're doing is a common occurrence this a _really bad idea_ in the first place. What you can do instead is build SQL to make your edits, where your run multiple SQL scripts in the same file or procedure based on a few inputs or (even better) fix the issue the requires these edits.

Comment: You'd probably be better served by writing an `UPDATE` \ `DELETE` statement to perform these operations on your tables instead of manipulating them using the editor. You can either perform them in series, or as batches (Using `GO` in SSMS).

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggests, this sounds like a truly awful idea. Additionally, I don't believe SSMS has support for this.

However, if you insist beyond all reason on continuing, one option is using MS Access. You can create an Access DB with [linked tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database/) that connect directly to the the SQL Server tables, so you can edit within the Access interface. If you wanted, this would also let you create forms and do things like data validation.